# Query huge files in s3 bucket

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, file, object, amazon-athena

I have huge files of sizes more than 10GB stored in s3 buckets.
I need to query the data in the files and extract some data as well as do some processing in the data.
AWS Athena is generally used for querying data in s3 but is there any other way? Athena does not seem helpful to me since the files are huge.

Comment: What kind of data is that?

Comment: What is the format of the files? Have you tried using the files in Amazon Athena? What problems have you experienced?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Athena is particularly good at processing large files.

Athena is charged based on data read from disk, so it can be lower-cost and faster to process files that are compressed, partitioned or in a columnar-based format.

See: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

Answer (score 0):

Even though Amazon Athena can handle large files pretty well but if you want to make your Athena queries cost-effective & performant, here are a few points you should definitely consider:

- First, you didn't mention the file type (CSV, TSV, Parquet, ORC, etc). The file type is extremely important as few formats are splittable, and few are not. Also, the compression type. **Splittable files allow the execution engine in Athena to split the reading of a file by multiple readers to increase parallelism.** Parquet and ORC are the two most common file formats and will give you better performance as well as cost as it will scan less amount of data.
- You also didn't mention how wide is your file. If you are querying only a few columns most of the time, consider **columnar data stores**. Again, Apache Parquet and Apache ORC are popular columnar data stores.
- How you are planning to use the "where" clause or filter? If you can categorize your data, do so using the **partition** mechanism. You can restrict the amount of data scanned by a query by specifying filters based on the partition. That will help you reduce your scan size which not only helps performance but also helps cost.

There are several other design practices you can follow, such as: optimizing file size, ORDER BY, joins, GROUP BY, or using bucketed/clustered column. You can run AWS Glue ETL (Serverless) jobs or jobs on Amazon EMR (managed Hadoop) to transform your data in the right format & shape before executing your Athena queries.

For more details, check out this blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/